# Passing a string with HTML tags from parent to child component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm trying to pass a string from my parent component to my child component. The string contains HTML tags with an HTML entity. This is an example of the template in the parent:

```html
<child-component i18n-componentContent="this is a test|for testing" componentContent='my test<sup>&reg;</sup>not working'></child-component>
```

on the child component side, I have the following:

```ts
    @Input() public componentContent: string;
    
...
        public ngOnInit() {
            console.log(this.componentContent);
        }
```

However, the value of

```ts
this.componentContent
```

is: `"my test"`

So, not the whole string is passed into the child component.

Why isn't the whole string passed into the child component?
What is needed to do to pass the whole string from the parent to the child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

The following html element is valid to pass into child component.

```
<child-component i18n componentContent='my test<sup>&reg;</sup>not working'></child-component>
```

if you are using `i18n-componentContent="this is a test|for testing"` inside the html element and Child Component get the `my test`. so remove this from html element `i18n-componentContent="this is a test|for testing"` then you can pass full string into child component

Comment: Thanks for your response but i18n-componentContent is necessary for localization of the string which I'm passing to the child component and it shouldn't have anything to do with the string being passed.

Comment: Surprisingly, removing i18n tag does fix the problem and the full string is passed to the child component but then I won't be able to do localization on the string since there would be no i18n attribute anymore. This seems to me a bug with Angular 4+ template engine.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a valid string, you need to escape html

```
componentContent='my test&lt;sup&gt;&reg;&lt;/sup&gt;not working'>
```

Comment: Thank you but I have tried that and what I get in the child component is: "my test\" so it gets cutoff after the first back slash.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you're converting the html tag to html entity before passing the string from parent to child and it is producing the the wrongly formatted string.

Instead that you can do the following:

Don't convert to html entity in your parent component and use `encodeURIComponent` function to encode the string in the parent component and in the child component use `decodeURIComponent` decode and after that do the conversion to html entity in the child component. I hope this way, you can avoid the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response but using encodeURIComponent causes template parse error: `componentContent= encodeURIComponent('my test not working')`